# ReactJS set dynamic input value based on Object

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, jsx

I have an Object like this:

[image]

And an object like this:

```
const subjectQuantities = {
      9: 2,
      11: 1,
    };
```

Where 9 and 11 are similar to the object `id` of first `Object` what I want to do is set the value of an input field dynamically so what I did is this:

```
{ Object.keys(subjects).map((item, i) => (
   <li className="travelcompany-input clearfix" key={i}>
      <span className="input-label">{ subjects[item].name }</span>
         <div className="input-group">
           { subjects[item].id in subjectQuantities ?
            <input className="form-control form-travelcompany-input" type="text" value=*DYNAMIC VALUE* min="0" max="10" />
             : <p>TEST</p>
             }
         </div>
   </li>
))}
```

How do I set the value of this input field dynamically based on the value of the subjectQuantities object.

Comment: maybe you want to use a *defaultValue* prop in the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you just need to do `{subjectQuantities[item]}`

See your example below.

```
{ Object.keys(subjects).map((item, i) => (
   <li className="travelcompany-input clearfix" key={i}>
      <span className="input-label">{ subjects[item].name }</span>
         <div className="input-group">
           { subjects[item].id in subjectQuantities ?
            <input className="form-control form-travelcompany-input" type="text" value={subjectQuantities[item]} min="0" max="10" />
             : <p>TEST</p>
             }
         </div>
   </li>
))}
```

Comment: I did it like this: value={this.subjectQuentaties[item]} why is it without this?

Comment: value={subjectQuantities[subjects[item].id]}